# NFS caches expiring unexpectedly

Tags: nfs, cache, timeout

I need to build a NFS4 + CacheFilesd setup on a high latency, low throughput link where local caches never expire. The only invalidation semantics must be the NFS Server callbacks when something is updated (which is working fine by the way, changes on the server files are instantly passed on to the client). This mount is read-only, so no locks are in place.

**The issue:** Even though it will always correctly read the requested file from the local cache, it keeps fetching the files attributes if said hasn't been accessed in the last 60 seconds or so regardless of actimeo=86400 being set. It seems to have something to do with how often the file is opened since it works perfectly fine as long as I keep opening it every 50 seconds or less.

**Proof of concept:**

(Server network latency is artificially set to 2000ms so I can clearly pinpoint when attribute checking is being performed)

Wait 50 seconds after each request yields 100% cache hit as intended. This will continue indefinitely:

```
root@client:~# while : ; do /usr/bin/time -f%e cat /nfs-mount/2bytes-file > /dev/null ; sleep 50 ; done
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
```

Now setting the delay between requests to 70 seconds, see how inconsistent the outcome is:

```
root@client:~# while : ; do /usr/bin/time -f%e cat /nfs-mount/2bytes-file > /dev/null ; sleep 70 ; done
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
0.00
6.00 # <- Attributes fetched. Debug log recorded "NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:69/68697599 fh_crc=0xb9b7a69e ct=2 info=0x26040)" 
4.00 # <- Attributes fetched. Debug log recorded "NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:69/68697599 fh_crc=0xb9b7a69e ct=2 info=0x26040)" 
0.00
0.00
0.00
6.00 # <- Attributes fetched. Debug log recorded "NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:69/68697599 fh_crc=0xb9b7a69e ct=2 info=0x26040)" 
4.00 # <- Attributes fetched. Debug log recorded "NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:69/68697599 fh_crc=0xb9b7a69e ct=2 info=0x26040)" 
0.00
0.00
0.00
```

Also, nfsstats adds an extra "getattr" when those delays occur:

```
create       delegpurge   delegreturn  getattr      getfh        link         
2         0% 0         0% 82        0% 177063   10% 87644     5% 0         0%
```

And finally, when delay is set to 110 seconds or more, every single request ends up getting checked against the server for some reason:

```
root@client:~# while : ; do /usr/bin/time -f%e cat /nfs-mount/2bytes-file > /dev/null ; sleep 110 ; done                                            
6.00
6.00
6.00
6.00
6.00
6.00
6.00
```

I managed to reproduce the very same behavior by serving this 2 bytes-long file via HTTP with nginx instead of "cat" and through "ioping" as well.

Cachefiled is not purging anything on its own since there is more than enough space in its partition:

```
/dev/vdb                20G  3,0G   16G  17% /disk2/fscache
```

I know it is only reaching out for the files' metadata and not the content itself because when I perform the same test against a 2GB file (which is more than the client's physical memory size), it hangs for 2 seconds (the network established delay) and then it starts reading the Cachefilesd locally cached file from the disk as expected.

I really don't understand what is going on during those 1-2 minutes that causes the client to recheck with the server for updates, and that kills off the purpose of my setup.

/etc/exports:

```
/cache 192.168.122.234(ro,async,no_subtree_check)
```

Client mount:

```
root@client:~# mount -t nfs4 -o lookupcache=all,actimeo=86400,nocto,ro,intr,soft,proto=tcp,async,fsc 192.168.122.1:/cache /nfs-mount
root@client:~# cat /proc/mounts | grep nfs
192.168.122.1:/cache /nfs-mount nfs4 ro,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,acregmin=86400,acregmax=86400,acdirmin=86400,acdirmax=86400,soft,nocto,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.122.234,fsc,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.122.1 0 0
```

Server is Centos 7, client is Ubuntu 16.04. Packages are obtained from the distro's repos.

root@client:~# dpkg -l | grep nfs
ii  libnfsidmap2:amd64                 0.25-5                                   amd64        NFS idmapping library
ii  nfs-common                         1:1.2.8-9ubuntu12                        amd64        NFS support files common to client and server
ii  nfs4-acl-tools                     0.3.3-3                                  amd64        Commandline and GUI ACL utilities for the NFSv4 client

I also tried using Ubuntu as a server and CentOS 7 as client with no avail.